Is there any alternatives to chanting a stotra and kavacham loudly?
Recently I came to a post in this website where it was stated that not chanting a stotra  aloud does not give any result s. But for today’s generation the situation is such that chanting a stotra or a kavacham aloud might cause some eerie situations around our people which I don’t want anyone to learn that someone is practising such things and want to maintain secrecy . So can anyone provide any alternatives to chanting a stotra or a kavacham that does not require chanting aloud but is completely scripture prescribed and provide the fruits of the chant . Thank you.

Don't chant it publicly. And reading aloud doesn't means that you have to yell it out.

I kind of whisper it so that it doesnt reach to other peoples ears . Is that wrong ? @অনু

Bhavam is key to spirtual journey as said by my appaji. Understand the essence of kavacham. Read it loid till you practice it right.
Then you can read it yourself and enjoy the bliss of bhava of the meaning. Visualise the feeling and meaning of slokas.
This is what I do,
